# adding values to table - ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError: update is defined by ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ok guys i have a problem - becouse i created a model and table AdminUser and then i trying to add values to it and then console print me ... any idea?

```
1.9.3-p286 :020 > AdminUser
 => AdminUser(id: integer, first_name: string, last_name: string, email: string, pass: string, date_reg: datetime, update: datetime) 

1.9.3-p286 :021 > AdminUser.all
  AdminUser Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "admin_user".* FROM "admin_user" 
 => [] 

1.9.3-p286 :022 > me =  AdminUser
 => AdminUser(id: integer, first_name: string, last_name: string, email: string, pass: string, date_reg: datetime, update: datetime) 
1.9.3-p286 :023 > me.new
ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError: update is defined by ActiveRecord
    from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:91:in `instance_method_already_implemented?'
    from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activemodel-3.2.8/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:263:in `block in define_attribute_method'
    from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activemodel-3.2.8/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:260:in `each'
    from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activemodel-3.2.8/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:260:in `define_attribute_method'
    from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activemodel-3.2.8/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:256:in `block in define_attribute_methods'
    from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activemodel-3.2.8/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:256:in `each'
    from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activemodel-3.2.8/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:256:in `define_attribute_methods'
    from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:66:in `block in define_attribute_methods'
    from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
    from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:63:in `define_attribute_methods'
    from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:168:in `respond_to?'
    from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:398:in `__run_callback'
    from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_initialize_callbacks'
    from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:501:in `initialize'
    from (irb):23:in `new'
    from (irb):23
    from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'1.9.3-p286 :024 >
```

Comment: Have you overwritten the update method of the AdminUser model?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `update` is a column in your model. But update is also a method defined by the Active Record. So rails won't know which your talking about if you try and access `admin.update`. You should be fine if you rename your `update` column to something else.

You might want to look at timestamps. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#special-helpers it looks to me like what you want to do with the `update` column.

Comment: Specifically, you want to rename it to `updated_at` and also use the related `created_at` field.